# Getting properties from ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell

I want to export the users in a specific AD group, but I want to filter the results and get only (First name, given name, display name, sAMAccountname, mail and homedirectory then export it into a CSV file.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity SerVAdmins -Properties GivenName, DisplayName, sAMAccountName, Mail, HomeDirectory |
    Out-File NewGroup.txt
```

It gives me the following error (roughly translated from German):

> No parameter was found matching the parameter name "Properties"

so I tried with `-Filter`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: according to this ... Get-ADGroupMember — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps ... there is NO parameter with that name. nor is there a `-Filter` parameter. [*grin*] if you want those details for the users, you will need to send the group members to `Get-ADUser`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Get-ADGroupMember` doesn't offer a way to select Properties of the users. Take a look at the command definition: [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps)

What you can do, is pipe the result and get each user with the properties with `Get-Aduser`.

Something like this should work:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "SerVadmins" |
    Get-ADUser -Properties GivenName, DisplayName, sAMAccountName, Mail,
        HomeDirectory |
    Export-Csv .\NewGroup.txt -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

Note that you can directly export the results in a csv using `Export-Csv`.